# how to display dicom image in matlab always with black background ?

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have a problem with some dicom images. Maybe they have a different image range. 
Generally it display as normal with black background but sometimes it display with white background. I have a question : what can I change it ? I would like to display images always with black background.

I would appreciate for any help/advice. I don't know what I should change ?

Agata

Comment: Have you tried the images in another DICOM viewer? Is it not possible that they were recorded with white backgrounds?

Comment: What is the value of a background pixel when the background is white and what is the value of a background pixel when the background is black ?  Do you use the built-in dicomread function ?

Comment: Yes I have already try display in Microdicom and it display with black background. But in matalab always with white. I am using simple : dicomread, mat2gray and imadjust ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of Photometric Interpretation (0028, 0004). This specifies the intended interpretation of the image pixel data. If the value is “MONOCHROME1” than the minimum sample value of pixel data is intended to be displayed as white (after any Modality LUT transformation) and maximum pixel value as black (inverted grayscale image)